# -[NSBundle pathForResource:ofType:inDirectory:] returns nil for localized resources

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I have a such bundle structure:

```
bundle's root
------atlases
------------en.lproj
--------------------test-hd.plist
------------es.lproj
--------------------test-hd.plist
```

But when I'm trying to get test-hd.plist for current localization using this code

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test-hd.plist" ofType:nil inDirectory:@"atlases"]
```

it always returns nil. Where is my mistake? How can I fix it?
P.S. "atlases" folder is added as folder reference and test-hd.plist is always available by straight path `[[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"atlases/en.lproj/test-hd.plist"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your directory structure is wrong. `en.lproj`, etc., should contain a directory called `atlases`, like this:

```
<bundle root>
|-- en.lproj
|---- atlases
|------ test-hd.plist
|-- es.lproj
|---- atlases
\------ test-hd.plist
```

Comment: Thx, it is working, but is there some way to make my directory structure working?

Comment: And it seems that according to Apple's documentation(example in `-[pathForResource:ofType:inDirectory:]` discussion) it must work as I've expected at the beginning... https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBundle/pathForResource:ofType:inDirectory:

Comment: @SiarheiFedartsou: No, that's how `NSBundle` searches for files.